# STL vector element removal efficiency

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector of objects. All object elements are unique. Functor is defined for unique id of class.

What will be more efficient to remove object element from vector

```
myvec.erase(std::remove_if(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), MyClass(id)), myvec.end());

//OR

itonmyvec = std::find_if(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), MyClass(id));
if(itonmyvec != myvec.end())
    myvec.erase(itonmyvec);
```

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it?

Comment: @delnan Can't this be answer to all SO questions? Why don't you read so and so book? Why don't you invent your own compiler? . Isn't this site for sharing of knowledge?

Comment: `erase` is a member function, not an `algorithm`.

Comment: STL implementations can vary, but they should be very close to equally bad. list is you friend for erase. btw, erasing end() is guaranteed to do nothing

Comment: @DivyangPatel No, not really. The effort to acquire this specific bit of knowledge is minimal, and everyone who answers that question would most likely have to do the exact same (it's unlikely that someone investigated this particular thing). There is a body of knowledge and experience that allows one to make an educated guess, but (1) describing the full reasoning goes into "too broad" territory, and (2) it's still just a guess, not a definite answer. The question "is A faster than B" is very narrow (too narrow perhaps), and the question "how do I decide what's faster" is too broad.

Comment: @sp2danny not true for the one iterator version of erase as said in cppreference : `The iterator pos must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the end() iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferencable) cannot be used as a value for pos.`

Comment: @delnan I agree that I should benchmark it. But as a user of SO, I believe if other members who has already bench-marked such scenario will save time of a fellow programmer. Sharing is caring. Plus, broad questions get closed as "Too-Broad" or "Not-to-the-Point" excuses by fellow members. Hence my question. :)

Comment: @DivyangPatel I see. My instant intuitive prediction was that nobody has a benchmark at hand, and the answers so far confirm this: Educated guesswork, but guesswork nonetheless.

Comment: @delnan It is impossible to provide a more exact answer without knowing how `MyClass` behaves - most importantly its size and the complexity of the comparison function.

Comment: @DivyangPatel - If someone on SO answered you by saying "the first code is faster", will you just take their word for it without benchmarking it yourself?

Comment: @gha.st Correct, that is one of many reasons I suggest OP benchmark it themselves. An answer that has a benchmark would either assume some particular example `MyClass`, or wait until OP has divulged these details. Note that the exact same problem applies to many other parameters: The contents of the vector (type and properties), its size, the typical position of the element searched, the context in which operation is performed, and so on. Choosing a representative, but simple enough benchmark is a *hard* problem and one of the reasons there are so many different, custom benchmarks.

Comment: @delnan As Scott Meyers says "when in doubt, do as ints do". I will say when MyClass is vague assume it as close to int (only member as int)... :)

Comment: @Kiroxas : seems you are right, sorry for outdated info, and thanks for alerting me to it.

Comment: That isn't exactly what Scott Meyers means. That statement is in the context of operator overloading and other semantics, not the use of members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual fastest method is neither. Both suffer from the additional constraint imposed in the Standard of preserving the relative order of the remaining elements, but that's not what you asked.

Hence, the fastest solution is to

1. find the element
2. swap it with the last element
3. erase the new last element.

This performs O(1) assignments, not O(N).

Comment: Perfect and efficient technique! I've added code for the same in a new answer below!

Comment: You can do better if you are willing to compromise exception safety, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using a vector, the two proposed implementations are almost identical.

The first one will run through the vector once, testing every element and compacting the vector at the same time and, then, finally destruct the last element and shorten the vector.

The second one will run through the vector until it finds the element, and then run through the rest of the vector to compact and finally shorten the vector.

As it turns out, the only real difference between the two versions is, that the second one will be able to save an average of O(n/2) comparisons. If comparisons are cheap, the performance will depend more on other properties of your system, e.g. which implementation is more cache friendly.

Therefore, the final answer can only be **benchmark it!**

P.S.: The first version must check if the result of `remove_if` is the `end` of the vector to be perfectly equivalent, so that check is done (or not done) in both versions in the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

Docs for [remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) say

> Removes all elements satisfying specific criteria from the range...

while [find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is specified to

> Returns the first element in the range...

Since you know that all elements are unique in your vector, you can safely stop searching it after the first match.  This means that the second form is likely faster for this specific case.

Note also that, as stated in comments, the first approach is wrong.  `remove_if` returns an iterator to the end of the (possibly updated) range.  You do not want to erase this from your vector - it is guaranteed not to match your target value.

Answer (score 0):

For the answer given by MSalters, I've written down the code. I couldn't add code into comments to that answer so adding it into new answer. Hope that helps!

```
//Remove 3rd element

vector<int> v {1,2,3,4,5};          //C++11 compiler needed!

vector<int>::iterator it1 = find(v.begin(), v.end(), 3); 

vector<int>::iterator it2 = --v.end();

std::swap(*it1, *it2);

v.pop_back();
```

Comment: You can do better if you are willing to compromise exception safety, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do better than the currently accepted answer *if* you are willing to compromise exception safety: Instead of swapping with the last element then calling `pop_back()`, you can simply *overwrite* the element to be removed with the last element. You have to iterate backwards, starting with the last element.

If you work with integers, it is fine and most likely measurable savings in time. If you work with who knows what classes that might throw on move copy, then you are in trouble, there goes your exception safety guarantee...

Here is an example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Vector, typename Pred>
void remove(Vector& v, Pred p) {

  auto last(v.rbegin());

  for (auto pos(last), rend(v.rend()); pos!=rend; ++pos) {

    if (p(*pos))
      // overwrite the element to be removed with the currently last element
      *pos = std::move(*last++);
  }

  v.erase(last.base(), v.end());  
}

// pretty print the vector for debugging
template <typename Vector>
void show(const Vector& v) {

  std::cout << "{ ";

  auto pos(v.begin());

  auto last(v.end());

  if (pos!=last) {

    --last;

    while (pos!=last)
      std::cout << *pos++ << ", ";

    std::cout << *last;
  }

  std::cout << " }" << std::endl;
}

// a simple-minded test that removes all 2s from the vector
void remove_2s(std::initializer_list<int> l) {

  auto equals_two = [](int i) { return i==2;};

  std::vector<int> v{l};

  remove(v, equals_two);

  show(v);
}

int main() {

  remove_2s({1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 2, 6});

  remove_2s({ 1, 2 });

  remove_2s({ 2, 1 });  

  remove_2s({ 2 });

  remove_2s({ 2, 2 });  

  remove_2s({  });

  remove_2s({ 1 });
}
```

Comment: There's also `move_if_noexcept`. But really, we're optimizing the O(1) part, while the search remains O(N).

Comment: @MSalters Yes, I know, it only affects the constant factors. As the question is formulated, the linear time search is inevitable so we can only improve on the constant factors.

Comment: @MSalters Ah, he only needs to remove a single element. My bad, didn't notice that. Then probably my "improvement" really doesn't matter much.

Comment: Ehh, I couldn't sign off on this in a code review. You're compromising exception safety all for what gain? It isn't worth it. You'll end up like Google, writing guidelines for future programmers that they can't use exceptions because of all the legacy code that isn't exception-safe.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, if you need "the fastest" algorithm and you know you are working with types that don't throw on move copy, then what I write above is safe. Nevertheless, you made me curious: *"You're compromising exception safety all for what gain?"* I will measure it during the week-end. While we are at it: I find a type pretty broken if it throws on move copy. I know it could happen but would that be a meaningful use case?